# What factors does the set-up time and Hold-time for an interface IC depend on?

Tags: i2c, communication, digital-communications, interface

I am working with EEPROM and QSPI Flash ICs. They have this electrical parameter called as Setup time and Hold time. I know we must not violate this in order for proper communication.

But my question is : different ICs have different values of setup and hold times.

Why is it so? On what basis is the setup and hold time value determined? Like, is it a standard for I2C Interface, SPI interface and so on? Or is it determined by someother value?

Please help me understand and provide clarity.

Answer (score 4):

Setup and hold are influenced by the logic speed, the amount of internal skew between the clock input and the destination logic, and the skew between the signal inputs to be sampled.

Faster logic will have shorter setup/hold time since it has less delay, and therefore skew. But this comes at the expense of power.

Chip designers also factor in how difficult it may be for a system to make timing in a given application. As a starting point they will often choose a setup/hold window that is 'reasonable' - say, 20% of the minimum clock cycle, that the data must be stable.

Most standards choose zero hold time for slow logic, but for faster I/O it is beneficial to specify a post-clock hold time to allow for shorter setup time.

I2C timing has a standard, defined by Philips (now NXP) as its benevolent owner. SPI/QSPI has no such standard, benevolent or otherwise. What this means is that if you are designing a system with SPI, you will need to survey various vendors to come up with a worst-case timing model, and design for that case. Fortunately, this isn't as hard as it seems. Choose a couple of leading vendors. You will see that in all likelihood they chose similar specs: 'reasonable' values for the clock speed and application.

Comment: Thank you. I was not able to get - "the amount of internal skew between the clock input and the destination logic" - In this, when you said, clock input (In Microcontroller context), does it mean, the Internal Microcontroller (or external microcontroller clock, whichever was enabled) clock? And when you said, "Destination logic" - does it mean the internal TTL, CMOS logic present inside the microcontroller pins?